# Finite groups are algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-groups

I am studying Linear Algebraic Groups on the book of T.A.Springer. I have some questions:

1. Why a finite group can become an algebraic group?
2. Could you give an example of a group that can not become an algebraic group?

Comment: Every finite subset of say the affine line, is a closed affine set.

Comment: 1. Try this first for the finite permutation group. 2. Take for instance the Higman group.

Answer (score 6):

I will assume that we have as a given that the group $\operatorname{GL}_n$ is an algebraic group for every $n\in\Bbb N$.

Then, note that every subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n$ which is a Zariski-closed subset (sometimes also referred to as a closed subgroup) is again an algebraic group: It is an algebraic variety because it is a closed subset of the variety $\operatorname{GL}_n$ and since the group operations are inherited, they are also morphisms of varieties.

The symmetric group $\mathfrak S_n$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n$ in the form of permutation matrices and every finite group is a subgroup of $\mathfrak S_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, hence every finite group is a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Is it possible to see what  $I$ and $ k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ will be, with say $S_3 \subset GL_6$ ?

Comment: Concerning $I$, that might be tricky and I do not know off hand, but the coordinate ring of a finite set of points is always just a product of as many copies of $k$ as there are points.

Comment: The rational map representing the multiplication by $g$ will be just a permutation of the $x_m$ ?